# Struggling with recursive bin algorithm: Fixed amounts of bin?

Tags: java, bin-packing

I am trying to figure this out:

> Given a set S of N positive integers the task is to divide them into K subsets such that the sum of the elements values in every of the K subsets is equal.

My approach is using a first fit decreasing algorithm. I sort the integers by size and fill them up:

```
public int getResult() {
    Collections.sort(in, Collections.reverseOrder()); // sort input by size (big to small)
    bins.add(new Bin(binSize)); // add first bin
    for (Integer currentItem : in) {
        // iterate over binlist and try to put the item into the first one it fits into
        boolean putItem = false; // did we put the item in a bin?
        int currentBin = 0;
        while (!putItem) {
            if (currentBin == bins.size()) {
                // item did not fit in last bin.
                // No clue what to do here
                putItem = true;
            } else if (bins.get(currentBin).put(currentItem)) {
                // item fit in bin
                putItem = true;
            } else {
                // try next bin
                currentBin++;
            }
        }
    }
    return bins.size();
}
```

Unfortunately I have no clue how to handle the situation if all bins are not full, but the last item doesn't fit anymore. 
I guess at this point I would like to reorganize the items and retry a different distribution. But how?

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now, I would be glad about any help!

Answer (score 0):

What would you do if you had actual bins in front of you? If a number doesn't fit in a bin, you need to go back to your last step, swap with a number that you had put in before. If that doesn't work, you need to go back, swap, and so on.

The title of your post says you're looking for a recursive solution. Your solution is not recursive. A recursive function calls itself, perhaps with a reduced set of parameters, and a recursive function has a "base case," or a way to know that it has gone as far as it can go and it can declare success.

Here is an example:

```
public int fibonacci(int n)  {
    // Here are the base cases (Fibonacci happens to have two)
    if (n==0) {
      return 0;
    }
    else if (n==1) {
      return 1;
    }

    // Otherwise, call this function again, changing the parameters
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

How would you write your recursive bin-filling function? You might place a number X from S, then call your function again with S without X. You should also pass along the bins. Think about what your base case is; I think you would declare success when S is empty and the bins are full. If S is not empty, try fitting the next X. If it doesn't fit, you'll need to backtrack, probably by doing something like "return false"... and your function needs to know what to do when a call to itself returns false.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your input!  

"If a number doesn't fit in a bin, you need to go back to your last step, swap with a number that you had put in before" 

Since I am working with sorted descending lists, I have a very difficult time grasping this correctly. I know that in the first run I distribute first the bigger ones, then the smaller ones.  But if I want to backtrack and create a different variant, am I not disturbing this pattern? And how would I express this - using list.get(1) instead of list.get(0) (the second biggest object instead of the first?)

Comment: In that case, you might be able to swap the bin instead of the number. For example, N1 goes to B1. N2 goes to B2. N3 doesn't fit in B3, so try taking N2 from B2 and put it in B3, then put N3 in B2. If that doesn't fit, take N1 from B1, put it in B2, and try N3 in B1. 

Or, maybe you don't need the sorted descending lists. 

What you have here is called a Bin Packing Problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem